# Show registration and login form on the Homepage

Tags: layout, login, register

I need to set Registration and Login form to show on homepage of my Magento site.

I have now tried to make custom extension that enables me to choose custom template inside admin for the homepage (CMS > homepage > design > select template) and I have copied magento registration form inside my custom template - but its not working. I need to render all of the layouts, and I am not seeing registration fields.

I supose more apropriate way would be to edit layouts and set homepage to load registration and login templates. Inside local.xml of my theme.

Can anyone give me a hint, is that possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a design tab in CMS pages. Add your layout XML in the "Layout Update XML" filed. Everything that you'd accomplish using layout.xml should be done from this field.

Comment: Thats not good answer. What I am trying to ask is - 
Is it correct and is it possible, from local.xml, update the layout in a way my registration and login forms are displayed on homepage..

Comment: From a best practice point of view - You shouldn't need to change the layout of a CMS page using local.xml, you should be able to do it from the design tab using your layout xml there.

It would be unnecessarily complex to try do it using local.xml

Answer (score 2):

Add this in one of your layout xml files:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```